# While trying to use sklearn in Jupyter Notebook, it gives me an error. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

These are the commands I am trying to launch

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
boston
```

And it returns me a plenty of errors

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16972/433790950.py in <module>
      2 import numpy
      3 import matplotlib
----> 4 from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
      5 boston = load_boston()
      6 boston

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._tags import (
     19     _DEFAULT_TAGS,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     21 
     22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 23 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
     24 from . import _joblib
     25 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
      8 
      9 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>
     20 # mypy error: Module 'numpy.core.numeric' has no attribute 'ComplexWarning'
     21 from numpy.core.numeric import ComplexWarning  # type: ignore
---> 22 import joblib
     23 
     24 from contextlib import suppress

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\__init__.py in <module>
    118 from .numpy_pickle import load
    119 from .compressor import register_compressor
--> 120 from .parallel import Parallel
    121 from .parallel import delayed
    122 from .parallel import cpu_count

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <module>
     24 from .logger import Logger, short_format_time
     25 from .disk import memstr_to_bytes
---> 26 from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
     27                                  ThreadingBackend, SequentialBackend,
     28                                  LokyBackend)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in <module>
     15 
     16 if mp is not None:
---> 17     from .pool import MemmappingPool
     18     from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
     19     from .executor import get_memmapping_executor

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\pool.py in <module>
     29 from io import BytesIO
     30 
---> 31 from ._memmapping_reducer import get_memmapping_reducers
     32 from ._memmapping_reducer import TemporaryResourcesManager
     33 from ._multiprocessing_helpers import mp, assert_spawning

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in <module>
     35 from .backports import make_memmap
     36 from .disk import delete_folder
---> 37 from .externals.loky.backend import resource_tracker
     38 
     39 # Some system have a ramdisk mounted by default, we can use it instead of /tmp

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in <module>
     47 import threading
     48 
---> 49 from . import spawn
     50 from multiprocessing import util
     51 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\spawn.py in <module>
     19 else:
     20     import msvcrt
---> 21     from .reduction import duplicate
     22     WINEXE = (sys.platform == 'win32' and getattr(sys, 'frozen', False))
     23     WINSERVICE = sys.executable.lower().endswith("pythonservice.exe")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py in <module>
    123 # global variable to change the pickler behavior
    124 try:
--> 125     from joblib.externals import cloudpickle  # noqa: F401
    126     DEFAULT_ENV = "cloudpickle"
    127 except ImportError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4 from .cloudpickle import *  # noqa
      5 from .cloudpickle_fast import CloudPickler, dumps, dump  # noqa
      6 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py in <module>
     62 
     63 try:  # pragma: no branch
---> 64     import typing_extensions as _typing_extensions
     65     from typing_extensions import Literal, Final
     66 except ImportError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py in <module>
   2141 
   2142     @_TypeAliasForm
-> 2143     def TypeAlias(self, parameters):
   2144         """Special marker indicating that an assignment should
   2145         be recognized as a proper type alias definition by type

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc'
```

Honestly I am not even able to understand which is exactly the error. I had tried to reinstall again Anaconda but the situation seems unchanged. It seems that the error relies in the packages but I don't know how I could solve it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the unprecise question.

Comment: Did conda provide any warnings or error messages when installing your environment? Also maybe post which versions you are using; you can find those using `conda list`.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of `typing_extensions`?